# Random installer pops up

Tags: windows-8, virus, updates, sony-vaio

A random installer pops up asking my language. It doesn't say what its going to install or anything. On Task Manager it says something like `glb1be9.tmp` when I close it a Vaio update window appears and says something like "to apply changes restart your computer"

I already did a quick scan with Malwarebytes and Avast and they found no infected items.

Is it a virus or is it Vaio update?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the SuperUser Stackexchange, Guest!

While I can't identify the package that's trying to install itself on your laptop, the behaviour and name seem suspicious. A great rule of thumb is if you didn't specifically ask for an install, were not expecting one, or appears beyond a reasonable doubt that it's something you don't want, don't allow it, and remove the source.

This certainly seems like something you don't want, so use the task manager to find where this file lives, kill the file, and delete it. If it appears again, it's a certain infection, and try something a bit stronger. I am surprised that Malwarebytes didn't pick it up. After deleting the file, set Malwarebytes to a more thorough scan.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to diagnose it.

Turn off Vaio updates and see if it goes away.
If you think it might be an ITunes update, turn off ITunes updates and see if it goes away.
I'm sure you get the rest of the pattern.

You could go directly to sony's website and download the latest drivers/software patches to check.  So you won't mess up anything by "Not" installing this unknown program.  Programs should identify themselves when installing (especially by companies with publicly traded stock, and Dell too).

If you have come to the end of the updating software then start taking more precautions involving updated virus scans, malware repellants and garlic.

Comment: how do i turn off vaio update?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is here.
https://us.en.kb.sony.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34087/c/65,66/kw/34087


The specifics may vary somewhat from version to version and model to model, however to turn off Vaio Update check the following:

1. Start Vaio Update Options by clicking Start, pointing to All Programs, pointing to VAIO Update, and clicking Vaio Update Options.

2. In the Vaio Update Options window, clear the 'Automatically check for updates on the support page' check box.

Comment: i cant find Vaio update options

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the Viao updater installed.

Comment: im pretty sure i have it installed, it appears in my start menu

Comment: When you start it up are there any options like "Automatically check for updates?"  If not you can uninstall it from the add/remove programs.

Comment: i just got a vaio update window that says something like "a program or update needs to restart or shut down the computer after the installation." should i accept it?